# Disable Scroll-Rails in Safari for iOS

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, safari

I built a [website](https://6047877ebe7911000787cc8e--boring-shockley-34d91f.netlify.app/) which relies on diagonal scrolling for its user-experience.

The current implementation works fine on every browser I tested (Chrome for mobile and desktop, Firefox on mobile and desktop, Safari on desktop)... except on Safari for iOS.

It appears as if there is some scroll-railing functionality going on: if the first scroll is diagonal, you can drag the page diagonally, horizontally and vertically.

However, as soon as you drag the page vertically or horizontally, scrolling "locks up" and you are limited to either scrolling X or Y, not both at once.

Is there any way to disable this feature, or at least work around it?

Apparently, you could set ms-scroll-rails to none to prevent this behavior on IE... Does Safari have a similar feature?

If you want to reproduce this problem, I made a simplified version of my website and it also can't be scrolled diagonally (X and Y at the same time) in Safari for iOS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height,initial-scale=1'>

    <title>Diagonal Scrolling on iOS</title>

    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/global.css'>
    <style>
        html {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        *,
        *::before,
        *::after {
            box-sizing: inherit;
        }

        body {
            width: 200vmax;
            height: 200vmax;
            background-color: #DFDBE5;
            background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' viewBox='0 0 100 100'%3E%3Cg fill-rule='evenodd'%3E%3Cg fill='%239C92AC' fill-opacity='0.4'%3E%3Cpath opacity='.5' d='M96 95h4v1h-4v4h-1v-4h-9v4h-1v-4h-9v4h-1v-4h-9v4h-1v-4h-9v4h-1v-4h-9v4h-1v-4h-9v4h-1v-4h-9v4h-1v-4h-9v4h-1v-4H0v-1h15v-9H0v-1h15v-9H0v-1h15v-9H0v-1h15v-9H0v-1h15v-9H0v-1h15v-9H0v-1h15v-9H0v-1h15v-9H0v-1h15V0h1v15h9V0h1v15h9V0h1v15h9V0h1v15h9V0h1v15h9V0h1v15h9V0h1v15h9V0h1v15h9V0h1v15h4v1h-4v9h4v1h-4v9h4v1h-4v9h4v1h-4v9h4v1h-4v9h4v1h-4v9h4v1h-4v9h4v1h-4v9zm-1 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-9-10h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm9-10v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-9-10h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm9-10v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-9-10h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm9-10v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-9-10h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9z'/%3E%3Cpath d='M6 5V0H5v5H0v1h5v94h1V6h94V5H6z'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
            margin: 0;
        }

        .heroview h1 {
            text-align: center;
            color: black;
            font-size: 4vh;
            line-height: 1.6;
            padding: 0;
            margin-top: 30vh;
        }

        .heroview h2 {
            text-align: center;
            color: black;
            font-size: 2.5vh;
            line-height: 1.6;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .heroview {
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 0;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: flex-start;
            align-items: center;
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <body>
        <div class="heroview">
            <h1>FixedLogo</h1>
            <h2>THIS IS SOME TEXT <br> DESCRIBING THE TITLE</h2>
        </div>
    </body>
</body>
<script>
    if ("scrollRestoration" in window.history) {
        window.history.scrollRestoration = "manual";
    }
    window.onload = () => { scrollTo(window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight / 2) };
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: You should show the related codes in your question.

Comment: @Raptor I added example code that reproduces this behavior on iOS Safari. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how iOS scroll railing works or what causes it.

I made it work by avoiding making the body having scrollbars, and instead placing the overflowed content inside a root div that has the same size as the viewport.

There's two problems with this solution.

1. The heroview text that's fixed on the center of the page, can't be interacted.

```css
.heroview {
  ...
  pointer-events: none; // disable pointer interaction
}
```

The reason why it needs that css property is since the root div's scrollbars are inside the viewport, the fixed hero has the same dimensions as the viewport, is covering it, so you wouldn't be able to scroll it.

You could interact with heroview's descendants by enabling pointer events.

```css
heroview h1 {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

But you run into the same problem if you tried to scroll and the mouse happened to be hovering over it and therefore no scrolling occurs.

I figured it was okay to post, because on your website, your center hero text which is html markup, can't be interacted either.

2. iOS Safari bottom navigation bar will not go away, since you'll be only scrolling within the root div.

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.root {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.container {
  width: 200vmax;
  height: 200vmax;
  background-color: #dfdbe5;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' viewBox='0 0 100 100'%3E%3Cg fill-rule='evenodd'%3E%3Cg fill='%239C92AC' fill-opacity='0.4'%3E%3Cpath opacity='.5' d='M96 95h4v1h-4v4h-1v-4h-9v4h-1v-4h-9v4h-1v-4h-9v4h-1v-4h-9v4h-1v-4h-9v4h-1v-4h-9v4h-1v-4h-9v4h-1v-4h-9v4h-1v-4H0v-1h15v-9H0v-1h15v-9H0v-1h15v-9H0v-1h15v-9H0v-1h15v-9H0v-1h15v-9H0v-1h15v-9H0v-1h15v-9H0v-1h15V0h1v15h9V0h1v15h9V0h1v15h9V0h1v15h9V0h1v15h9V0h1v15h9V0h1v15h9V0h1v15h9V0h1v15h4v1h-4v9h4v1h-4v9h4v1h-4v9h4v1h-4v9h4v1h-4v9h4v1h-4v9h4v1h-4v9h4v1h-4v9zm-1 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-9-10h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm9-10v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-9-10h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm9-10v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-9-10h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm9-10v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-10 0v-9h-9v9h9zm-9-10h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9zm10 0h9v-9h-9v9z'/%3E%3Cpath d='M6 5V0H5v5H0v1h5v94h1V6h94V5H6z'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  margin: 0;
}

.heroview h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 4vh;
  line-height: 1.6;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 30vh;
}

.heroview h2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 2.5vh;
  line-height: 1.6;
  padding: 0;
}

.heroview {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
  <div class="root">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="heroview">
        <h1>FixedLogo</h1>
        <h2>THIS IS SOME TEXT <br> DESCRIBING THE TITLE</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I tested with iOS 14.3

Comment: thank you so much for your effort... this at least works in my example webpage. However, when it comes to the real website, it kind of breaks the window elements. I had the body with a width of 200vw width and 200vh height as a grid, in which I placed the window elements. If I try to reproduce your code in my project however, it seems like it breaks as soon as I give a "parent element" a width wider than the container element

Comment: I tried making it work with your website, and I'm having trouble as well

Comment: Thanks again! 
After many hours of trying to make it work, I finally got it done. I basically modeled the whole index structure after your answer and then only add "overflow: scroll;" conditionally to the root element, when I detect iOS Safari to prevent bad scrolling behavior on other devices. I use the svelte framework for my website, but maybe just looking at the index.html file will help you understand how it works: https://github.com/Theo-Steiner/MortimerBaltus.com/blob/main/public/index.html . Once again: thank you @CalebTaylor